# How can i send a Image from Android File System via SuperAgent

Tags: android, react-native, superagent

In my React Native Android App i am using Superagent for Requests.
Now i need to send an Image to my backend. My backend is awaiting a post with an image URL/Path. I managed it, egtting the Image which is in the Filesystem, in this example the image is a JPG

```
postUserAvatar: function (userToken, image) {
    superAgentRequest
        .post(API_URL + 'user/avatar')
        .set({
            'Authorization': userToken
        })
        .send({
            'image': image
        })
        .end(function (err, res) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(res.text))
        })
}
```

Now this isn´t working at all. Maybe someone used Superagent for requests and sending images to backend. I would like to see the code snippet if possible or get some hints please :)

**This is how my image path from filesystem looks like**

> '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/9a92e201-4740-4caa-b96d-8a4a5903a0e8.jpg'

**UPDATE**

According to the latest answer i used the .attach to send my image file. It still doesn´t work. This is how my code looks at present:

```
 postUserAvatar: function (userToken, filePath, fileName) {
    console.log('FileName: ' + fileName);
    console.log('FilePath: ' + filePath);
    request
        .post(API_URL + 'user/avatar')
        .set({
            'Authorization': userToken,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        })
        //.send({image: image})
        .attach('image', filePath, fileName)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log(JSON.parse(res.text));
            }
        })
```

FilePath:

> '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/9a92e201-4740-4caa-b96d-8a4a5903a0e8.jpg'

FileName:

> '9a92e201-4740-4caa-b96d-8a4a5903a0e8.jpg

Answer (score 1):

According to `SuperAgent` docs, you should use `.attach` after ensuring path of your file:

```
postUserAvatar: function (userToken, image) {
    superAgentRequest
       .post(API_URL + 'user/avatar')
       .set({
             'Authorization': userToken
        })
        .attach('image',image)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(res.text))
        })
}
```